# How can you update values in a dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So as far as I know Apache Spark doesn't has a functionality that imitates the ***update*** SQL command. Like, I can change a single value in a column given a certain condition. The only way around that is to use the following command I was instructed to use (here in Stackoverflow): `withColumn(columnName, where('condition', value));`

However, the condition should be of `column` type, meaning I have to use the built in column filtering functions apache has (`equalTo`, `isin`, `lt`, `gt`, etc). Is there a way I can instead use an SQL statement instead of those built in functions?

The problem is I'm given a text file with SQL statements, like `WHERE ID > 5` or `WHERE AGE != 50`, etc. Then I have to label values based on those conditions, and I thought of following the `withColumn()` approach but I can't plug-in an SQL statement in that function. Any idea of how I can go around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to go around this:

You want to split your dataset into two sets: the values you want to update and the values you don't want to update

```
Dataset<Row> valuesToUpdate = dataset.filter('conditionToFilterValues');
Dataset<Row> valuesNotToUpdate = dataset.except(valuesToUpdate);

valueToUpdate = valueToUpdate.withColumn('updatedColumn', lit('updateValue'));

Dataset<Row> updatedDataset = valuesNotToUpdate.union(valueToUpdate);
```

This, however, doesn't keep the same order of records as the original dataset, so if order is of importance to you, this won't suffice your needs.

In PySpark you have to use .subtract instead of .except

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataFrame, you can register that dataframe as temp table,
using df.registerTempTable("events")

Then you can query like,
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM events "+)

Comment: But I still won't be able to update the dataset because spark doesn't accept the **UPDATE** statement

Comment: Once you get the filtered dataframe based on the input condition, you can create an new column with updated values in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

**`when`** clause translates into **`case clause`** which you can relate to SQL case clause.

**Example**

```
scala> val condition_1 = when(col("col_1").isNull,"NA").otherwise("AVAILABLE")
condition_1: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CASE WHEN (col_1 IS NULL) THEN NA ELSE AVAILABLE END
```

or you can chain **`when`** clause as well

```
scala> val condition_2 = when(col("col_1") === col("col_2"),"EQUAL").when(col("col_1") > col("col_2"),"GREATER").
     | otherwise("LESS")
condition_2: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CASE WHEN (col_1 = col_2) THEN EQUAL WHEN (col_1 > col_2) THEN GREATER ELSE LESS END

scala> val new_df = df.withColumn("condition_1",condition_1).withColumn("condition_2",condition_2)
```

Still if you want to use table, then you can register your dataframe / dataset as temperory table and perform sql queries

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")//spark 2.1 +
df.registerTempTable("tempTable")//spark 1.6
```

Now, you can perform sql queries

```
spark.sql("your queries goes here with case clause and where condition!!!")//spark 2.1
sqlContest.sql("your queries goes here with case clause and where condition!!!")//spark 1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Dataset<Row>`
you can update dataset with:

```java
Dataset<Row> ratesFinal1 = ratesFinal.filter(" on_behalf_of_comp_id != 'COMM_DERIVS' ");
ratesFinal1 = ratesFinal1.filter(" status != 'Hit/Lift' ");

Dataset<Row> ratesFinalSwap = ratesFinal1.filter (" on_behalf_of_comp_id in ('SAPPHIRE','BOND') and   cash_derivative != 'cash'");
ratesFinalSwap = ratesFinalSwap.withColumn("ins_type_str",functions.lit("SWAP"));
```

adding new column with value from existing column:

```java
ratesFinalSTW = ratesFinalSTW.withColumn("action", ratesFinalSTW.col("status"));
```