# How to update a Column values in Spark Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a Spark Dataset loaded in memory and persisted to the parquet files. There is a UI application where a user may define the value to be populated in the particular Column of the Dataset. It could be a formula where the value will depend on the values in the different Columns of the same Dataset Row.

Initially I thought about brute force solution and wanted to iterate throw the List and update certain Column value, but it could be highly inefficient.

List listOfRows = dataframe.collectAsList();

```
for(Row oneRow : listOfRows) {
 // Process every single Row
}
```

Then I tried to use Dataset.withColumn(..) api :

```
for (String cn : cvtCols) {
            if (cn.equalsIgnoreCase(columnName)) {      
                dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(cn, <some value here>);
            }
        }
```

However, that updated the whole dataset at once and I don't see how to inject a formula here, in my case it's Javascript, where there is a potential dependency on the other Column values in the same row.

Comment: You know that the data in Spark is immutable? It’s not a “database.”

Comment: I do know that, but withColumn probably creates new dataset under the hood. I tested Dataset.withColumn and it works for every row and Dataset gets updated

Comment: Try looking at [How can you update values in a dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615406/16653700)

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is very costly in resources. By calling the `collectAsList()` action, you are asking spark to return all the the elements of the dataframe as a list to the driver program. This case can cause an OutOfMemoryError.
Also, any operation done after that action will be done only on the driver program without using the spark executors.

In your case, you need to use `withColumn()` without the `for` loop. Then, to inject the formula that depends on other columns you can replace the `<some value here>` with an expression that uses`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col`. Refer to this link for more details https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-withcolumn/

Comment: There is a problem in using "withColumn". We have an existing API  that takes a Row, represented as a Map as a parameter and returns the value and I don't have the formula at the time of execution.

Comment: Can't you call the API in the ``<some value here>` part ? 
Otherwise, maybe spark UDFs can be usefull in your case.

Comment: yes, I can, but then I need to pass a value from every Row to this api and the only way to do that is to iterate through every row, collect data from the columns in  that Row and then pass it to the API to get new value. It's not a trivial task.

Comment: The `withColumn()` function will be applied to each row. You don't need to iterate through all the rows.
For example, lets say you API signature is `String getRes(String name)`. In this case, you need to call your API as follows: `df.withColumn("name", getRes(col("name")))`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that parameters to "getRes" must be a unique Map<String,Object> for every row. Ideally it should be a List<Map<ColumnName key,ColumnValue value>>. I just don't see how it's possible.
 df.withColumn(...) works great when you know what operations on what columns you need to take. Unfortunately it's not my case. I have an API I need to invoke and I need to pass Map<ColumnName,ColumnValue> to it, then an API calculates the value and returns it.

Comment: I misunderstood you requirement.
I can't help you more becuase i'm missing a lot of details, like an example, the logic on which you choose the column that you are going to pass to your API, ...

Comment: I solved it. I will post an answer later. Thank you for your help!